# OData: How to use DataMember names of DTO models as filters with ODataQueryOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm developing filtering for existing WEB API project. It was decided to use OData for that. I have existing Core infrastructure ( Core EF entities and DbContext). Also, for Web API I use DTO models of those Core entities. All DTO models have data annotations. The issue is OData filtering does not work with data annotation names. I've tried to follow suggestions from other topics but got failures. I will appreciate any suggestion about this issue.

Microsoft.AspNet.OData 7.2.1 is installed.

The Core entities:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Staff
{
    public Staff
        {
            this.StaffRoles = new HashSet<StaffRole>();
        }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool? ExternalStaff { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StaffLogin { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<StaffRole> StaffRoles { get; set; }
}
```

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        this.StaffPersons = new HashSet<Staff>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Staff> StaffPersons { get; set; }
}
```

DTO model:

```
[DataContract]
public class StaffDTO
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "is_status_active")]
    public bool IsStatusActive { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "is_staff_external")]
    public bool IsStaffExternal { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "roles")]
    public IEnumerable<StaffRoleDTO> StaffRoles { get; set; }
}
```

WebApiConfig:

```
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.ModelAliasingEnabled = true;

    builder.EntitySet<StaffDTO>("Staffs").EntityType.Name= "Staff";
    var staffType = builder.EntityType<StaffDTO>();

    config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", null, builder.GetEdmModel());
    config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
```

Web API controller:

```
public class CommonODataController : ODataController
{
    private IMapper mapper;

    private MyDbContext dbContext;

    public CommonODataController(IMapper mapper, MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<StaffViewModel> GetStaff()
    {
        IQueryable<Staff> staffQuery = this.dbContext.Staffs
            .Include(x => x.Contact)
            .Include(x => x.StaffRoles);

        var staffDTOQuery = this.mapper.ProjectTo<StaffDTO>(staffQuery);

        return staffDTOQuery;
    }
}
```

AutoMapper config:

```
CreateMap<Staff, StaffDTO>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PrimaryKey))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.FirstName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Contact.FirstName))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.LastName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Contact.LastName))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.IsStatusActive, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Active))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Login, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.StaffLogin))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Email, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Contact.Email))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.IsStaffExternal, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ExternalStaff))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.StaffRoles, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.StaffRoles));
```

When I send request ".../staff?$top=50&$filter=first_name eq 'some name'" I get the error "Instance property 'first_name' is not defined for type 'StaffDTO'}".

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Does 
    staffType.Property(x => x.FirstName).Name = "first_name";
resolve the issue?

Comment: @earloc no, it does not help. I've tried that.

Comment: I had a similar situation a while ago. Solved it via seperate DTO´s whose property-signatures match the desired naming (instead of using alternating Names in DataMemberAttribute)